# How to separate development and production environments in shadow-cljs?

Tags: clojurescript, shadow-cljs

I want to separate development and production environment variables for my shadow-cljs which is running in conjunction with a lein app through the Luminus template. My production environment is a docker container running on heroku.
It should work in a way that I can import a map, say config, and so that I can access the keys using (:some-key config), or something similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

There is built-in support for separating release and dev configuration.

https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#_release_specific_vs_development_configuration

The "import a map and access by key" you are asking for is not supported by shadow-cljs and would be something a library would provide instead.

I also do not recommend using environment variables to configure a build.

Also note that shadow-cljs configuration is about build time. If you want to access the "environment" at runtime you do not make it part of the build at all. Say you create a `:node-script` build running in `node`. You can just access `js/process.env.SOME_ENV` at runtime via normal code.

Comment: Is there a recommended way of supporting multiple environments from the same build-id (eg. :app). I.e. having the following environemnts "local", "testing", "staging" and "production" and giving them each a specific (different) backend URL.I foundt https://github.com/mhuebert/shadow-env but TBH it seems overly complicated.

Comment: My advice is to keep "runtime configuration" out of your build config and instead supply it at runtime. I don't know what you are building but `:browser` targets for example can get configuration from the HTML or via XHR requests. You can put it into the build via https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#shadow-env with `:closure-defines` if you prefer that route.